# How to find out why my Ubuntu server is crashing each day

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server-crashes

I have been running Ubuntu server 14.04 for around two years. But sinds a few weeks the server crashes and burns each day. It is unclear to me why this is happening.

I checked log files in `/var/log` but these do not provide any information on why or even that the server is going down.

Is there is structured approach to troubleshooting these crashes? Can I increase loging somehow / somewhere?

Does it mean something anything there is no information indicating problems of some sort? This type of crash is similar to just turing power off maybe?

Comment: As @CM saids, maybe a hardware problem. Replace the power source.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to inspect the syslog if the logging suddenly stopped at some point then resumed showing signs of booting up.  This might indicate a server crash due to hardware.

RAM issue is possible.  We also encountered a similar problem with one of our servers overheating and suddenly powering off.  I hope this helps.